# hibernate MySQL57Dialect why is it trying to drop indexes on update?

Tags: hibernate

When I boot up my server on an empty database, it tried to DROP indexes.  Why would it do this?  I would think it would check for existence and want to leave in place (especially since we deploy to production and would NOT want to delete and recreate indexes on production instance).  We are getting the following error as it tried to drop it...

```
alter table SIMPLE_STORAGE drop index UKoxri4n3k816chptlt177n6sf0 

2020-02-09 10:32:01,265 [main][] [-] Caller+0    at net.sf.log4jdbc.Slf4jSpyLogDelegator.exceptionOccured(Slf4jSpyLogDelegator.java:111)
 ERROR: 1. Statement.execute(alter table SIMPLE_STORAGE drop index UKoxri4n3k816chptlt177n6sf0) alter table SIMPLE_STORAGE drop index UKoxri4n3k816chptlt177n6sf0 

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Can't DROP 'UKoxri4n3k816chptlt177n6sf0'; check that column/key exists
```

Right after dropping it, it then recreates it....

```
2020-02-09 10:32:01,265 [main][] [-] Caller+0    at net.sf.log4jdbc.Slf4jSpyLogDelegator.sqlOccured(Slf4jSpyLogDelegator.java:226)
 INFO: alter table SIMPLE_STORAGE add constraint UKoxri4n3k816chptlt177n6sf0 unique (pluginKey, mapKey)
```

Why is it doing this?  I remember postgres adapter never did this so it would not blow away and recreate my indexes.

Oh, my persistence.xml has this by the way

```
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

thanks,
Dean

Comment: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hbm2ddl-auto-update-recreating-existing-indexes-after-drop/3991 - of course using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` in production is not a good idea, but I’m creating (flyway-) update-scripts with the help of `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate` and see the same drop-index-create-index stuff, although apparently only for unique indexes. Maybe @vlad-mihalcea has an explanation for this? Was definitely not the case in Hibernate 4.3.11 (we are in the process of upgrading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably those are dropped to prevent eventual constrain checks and failures due to those checks. The similar thing is done when you import mysql dump file - except then indexes are disabled with mysql internal-use-only directives.

Postrgres does not have to do that as constrains are validated after work is done.